# javascript assertion between two numbers range

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress, ui-automation

How do I find a assertion for a value between two numbers

```
let lastArrayAmountValue=50;
assert.equal(lastArrayAmountValue, '5');
```

I want to assert whether the number is between `5-10`
This is the test am doing on cypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
expect(lastArrayAmountValue).to.be.within(5,10)
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#BDD-Assertions

looks like that ability is built into cypress

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply `within` to an asynchronous element, move it into `.should()` to trigger retry of the assertion.

For example,

```js
cy.get(elementArraySelector)
  .last()
  .should($el => {
    const value = +$el.text() || 0; 
    expect(lastArrayAmountValue).to.be.within(5,10)  // retry until timeout
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this. Number is greater than equal to 5 and less than equal to 10.

```js
cy.wrap(lastArrayAmountValue).should('be.gte', 5).and('be.lte', 10)
```